# C++ Can't find error

Tags: c++

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I can't get it to run.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

   int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        int a[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        skipOne(a, 2);  
    }

    void skipOne(int * array, int n)
    {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++)
        {
            if (i != n)
            {
                total = + array[i];
            }           
        }    
        cout << "The total is: " << total << endl;
    }
```

This is what I went with from your help below.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void skipOne(vector<int> & array, int n)
{

    int total = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i != n)
        {
            total *= array[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "The total is: " << total << endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<int> a = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    skipOne(a, 0);
    skipOne(a, 1);
    skipOne(a, 2);
    skipOne(a, 3);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(array)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Please tell us the error you're seeing, or the unexpected behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Additionally to what @JohnnyMopp said, the compiler should tell you that it doesn't know anything about `skipOne` in `_tmain`

Comment: `= +` doesn't do what you think it does either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to declare skipOne earlier and use vector.size()

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void skipOne(int * array, int n);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<int> a = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    skipOne(a, 2);  
}

void skipOne(vector<int> & array, int n)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i != n)
        {
            total = + array[i];
        }           
    }    
    cout << "The total is: " << total << endl;
}
```

Comment: There is still a bug in there, that will make him overrun the array on 64bit systems

Comment: There is also another bug: `total` will be set to the last non-matching value, not the sum of the non-matching values.

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof` doesn't work on passed arrays or pointers. You have to pass the array length as an argument.

Besides, you have to declare functions before you use them.

```
void skipOne(int * array, int n, int length); // declare here

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    skipOne(a, 2, 4);  
}

void skipOne(int * array, int n, int length)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) // use length here
    {
        if (i != n)
        {
            total += array[i]; // += instead of = +
        }           
    }    
    cout << "The total is: " << total << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sizeof( array ) that is equivalent to sizeof( int * ) because the type of array is int * usually equal to 4 or 8 depending on the used system. It has nothing common with the number of elements in array a. 
Also any name used in a program shall be defined before its usage. You use function skipOne in main but it is not declared yet.

So the valid code can look the following way

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int skipOne( const int *, int, int );

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    std::cout << "The total is: " << skipOne( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ), 2 ) 
              << std::endl;
}

int skipOne( const int * array, int n, int k )
{
    int total = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( i != k )
        {
            total += array[i];
        }           
    }

    return total;    
}
```

Also you could use standard container std::array. In this case the code would look simpler. For example

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int skipOne( const std::array<int, 4> &, int );

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::array<int, 4> a = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    std::cout << "The total is: " << skipOne( a, 2 ) 
              << std::endl;
}

int skipOne( const std::array<int, 4> &a, int k )
{
    int total = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ )
    {
        if ( i != k )
        {
            total += a[i];
        }           
    }

    return total;    
}
```